# Is there any Out of the box way to compress the content stored in ACS Enterprise version?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

Team,
is there any way by which we can compress stored content in Alfresco 7.x onwards?
Let me know if any link/references.

Comment: Compress the files before you upload them?

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I could give is to use transparent mechanisms provided by modern filesystems and *not* to try to add such features into the Alfresco application. On Linux we store alf_data and the solr index on zfs having compression enabled, which comes with great performance and a very little footprint (don't expect the same for other systems).

If performance does not have that high prio you could also enable de-duplication on block level on your alf_data zfs dataset which could reduce the space occupied by the alfresco nodes dramatically but this then of course consumes a lot of RAM and cpu to always compare all blocks written.